# tf.decode_csv lasts too long

Tags: tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow v0.8, and it's strange that it takes around 5 minutes to print the second `print time.time()`. I thought `tf.decode_csv()` would just simply add an operation into the graph without doing any computation.

**Why does it take so long to call `tf.decode_csv()`?**

```py
def main(argv=None): 
  # deal with arguments
  with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once(train_set_filename + "*"))

    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    _, line = reader.read(filename_queue)

    default = [[-1.0] for x in range(image_size * image_size * channels + 1)]
    print time.time()
    line = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=default)
    print time.time()
    label = line[0]
    feature = tf.pack(list(line[1:]))

    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=default)` takes a lot of time because you use so many columns.
I don't know your image_size, but if it is around `200` you are trying to set `120,001` columns to your csv, which is huge. You are right, TensorFlow is not doing any computation, but it has to build the graph properly and with that much columns it takes a lot of time !

I strongly advise you to **not use csv format for images**. Instead you should store your images in JPEG format, and use `tf.image.decode_jpeg()`.

Comment: yes, my image_size is 224. thanks for the suggestion, I will have a try tomorrow.